# ubuntu-22.04.3-live-server-amd64 LTS device gets public ipv6 assigned but not able to access it

Tags: networking, ipv6

Since I have Internet connection from an ISP that does not give public ipv4 and keeps the connection in cg-NAT but too my surprise I found out that it is assigning public ipv6 to all my devices.

After that I started investigating and found out that it is indeed the public ipv6 address.

I installed nginx on other devices to check the ipv6 working or not, and I was able to access the nginx server from outside the network I also assigned that ipv6 to a domain and checked from mobile data visiting that domain, and I was able to reach nginx server there too.

The problem is all my other devices can be accessed from their public ipv6, but I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 server on my laptop that I was not using for the purpose of making it a home server this device too gets public ipv6 assigned.
I changed the IP's for security purposes.

Here is the ifconfig response :

```
enp7s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.25  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::7890:ba98:7654:3210  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    inet6 2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
    ether 47:28:5a:24:88:95  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 1757  bytes 272327 (272.3 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 555  bytes 63430 (63.4 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

But this device is not reachable from the internet through its ipv6.

Here is the ip -6 route response :

```
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2001:0db8:85a3:0000::/64 dev enp7s0 proto ra metric 100 expires 86180sec pref medium
fe80::/64 dev enp7s0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium 
default via fe80::1 dev enp7s0 proto ra metric 100 expires 1580sec mtu 1492 pref medium
```

Also, when I ping ipv6.google.com I get this response

```
PING ipv6.google.com(del03s17-in-x0e.1e100.net (2404:6800:4002:80c::200e)) 56 data bytes
```

But after that, the ping gets stuck and does not response.I don't think I can reach ipv6 link from this device but why I get public ipv6 assigned to this device but not able to access it, but other device can do.

I have also allowed ipv6 incoming connection on router firewall.

What should I do?

Comment: There is no Ubuntu release "Ubuntu 22". All Ubuntu release have a number schemes ab.xy, e.g. 22.04. Please edit your question and state the correct Ubuntu version you are using.

Comment: @guiverc i am using ubuntu-22.04.3-live-server-amd64 which is the LTS version and i downloaded from Ubuntu download page.

Comment: The IPv6 address 2001:DB8::/32 is a reserved address to be used only as a documentation-only prefix. I don't think these kind of addresses are reachable from the Internet. I think your ISP is using these addresses for an obscure purpose! See: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3849.html

Comment: @FedKad I changed the IP's for security purposes